# Accessing files under asset subfolder by Id or Name android studio

Tags: android, file, assets, subdirectory

I have two sub-folders under assets folder i.e one for English and another for Turkish which contains respective **.mp3** files. All i want to know is how to access a file places under these folders.

Comment: You should place them in `raw` folder and access them like `R.raw.id`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  InputStream is = getAssets().open("eng/file1.mp3");
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
  String line = null;
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
  {
    //Logic here
  }
  br.close();
```